# Why do the following 2 of 3 versions std::visit not work

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming, c++20, variant

I was trying to use a `std::visit` to access a member in a variant, and throw an error if that member wasn't available.

I was able to get a working solution but I found the errors in for my first two attempts unintelligible.

Does anybody know why "version 1" and "version 2" don't work?

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

struct a
{
    int value=32;
};

struct b : a
{

};

struct c
{
    //empty
};

using t = std::variant<std::monostate,a,b,c>;

struct wacky_visitor{
    // Version 1 (doesn't work)
    // bool operator()(const auto& l, const auto& r)
    // { 
    //     throw std::runtime_error("bad"); 
    // };
    // Version 2 (doesn't work)
    // template <typename L, typename R> 
    // bool operator()(const L& l, const R& r)
    // { 
    //     throw std::runtime_error("bad"); 
    // };
    // Version 3 (works)
    template <typename L, typename R> 
    std::enable_if_t<!(std::is_base_of_v<a, L> && std::is_base_of_v<a, R>), bool> operator()(const L& l, const R& r)
    { 
        throw std::runtime_error("bad"); 
    };
    //Shared
    template <typename L, typename R> 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<a, L> && std::is_base_of_v<a, R>, bool> operator()(const L& l, const R& r)
    { 
        return l.value < r.value;
    };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<t> foo_bar = {a(),b()};
        const auto comparison = [](const t &lhs, const t &rhs) {
        return std::visit(wacky_visitor{}, lhs, rhs);
    };
    std::sort(foo_bar.begin(), foo_bar.end(), comparison);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/1c488v

Comment: copy the error message here.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont The code runs fine now, but the error message generated by gcc and clang (see godbolt) exceeds both compilers' output limits :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version 1 and version 2 mean exactly the same thing, so I'll only consider version 2.

When you invoke `wacky_visitor`, you have two overload choices:

```cpp
// first overload
template <typename L, typename R>
bool operator()(L const&, R const&);

// second overload
template <typename L, typename R>
???? operator()(const L& l, const R& r)
```

Where the `????` is this `enable_if` "constraint" (I use quotes because it's the best C++17 could do as far as constraints go, but it's not a proper constraint, see below). In some cases, that's an invalid type, so the overload will be removed from consideration. But if it *is* a valid type, then... well, our two overloads are exactly the same. Both are exact matches in both arguments and there is nothing whatsoever to distinguish them.

Your 3rd version works because the negated `enable_if` condition ensures that exactly one of the two overloads is viable, so overload resolution always has exactly one candidate to choose from -- which then becomes trivially the best.

---

It's easier to just use `if constexpr` and have a single overload:

```cpp
template <typename L, typename R> 
bool operator()(const L& l, const R& r)
{ 
    if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<a, L> && std::is_base_of_v<a, R>) {
        return l.value < r.value;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("bad");
    }
};
```

---

In C++20, Concepts has the added functionality that a *constrained* function template is preferred to an unconstrained one. Which means you could write it like this:

```cpp
// first overload as before, whichever syntax
template <typename L, typename R>
bool operator()(L const&, R const&);

// second overload is now constrained
template <typename L, typename R> 
    requires std::is_base_of_v<a, L> && std::is_base_of_v<a, R>
bool operator()(const L& l, const R& r);
```

If the 2nd overload isn't viable, the 1st one is called -- as before. But now, if the 2nd overload is viable, it is able to be preferred to the 1st anyway.

The second overload can also be written like this:

```cpp
template <std::derived_from<a> L, std::derived_from<a> R>
bool operator()(const L& l, const R& r);
```

Which means approximately the same thing.

Comment: the other trick that works is variardics; they lose ties.

Comment: @Berry I've been thinking about this question from a code gen perspective.  Image that you have a bunch of variant types, maybe 200 unique variants. Will both "version 3" and the posted answer create 200 x 200 individual functions?

Comment: @Mikhail Yes they will.

Comment: @Barry what about version 1 or version 2?